# How to avoid deprecation warning for stub_chain in RSpec 3.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

When I run a test with stub_chain, I'll get a deprecation warning.

```
describe "stubbing a chain of methods" do
  subject { Object.new }

  context "given symbols representing methods" do
    it "returns the correct value" do
      subject.stub_chain(:one, :two, :three).and_return(:four)
      expect(subject.one.two.three).to eq(:four)
    end
  end
end
```

Deprecation Warnings:
Using `stub_chain` from rspec-mocks' old `:should` syntax without explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use the new `:expect` syntax or explicitly enable `:should` instead.

How this warning can be avoided?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec do |c|
    c.syntax = [:should, :expect]
  end
end
```

Notice that it's setting the rspec-mocks syntax, not the rspec-expectations syntax, as Paul's answer shows.

Comment: See [related for circa 2015/2016 way of doing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28050261/issue-with-stubs-and-rspec-old-syntax).

Answer (score 76):

<strike>In order to get rid of the warning with your code as-is, you'll have to explicitly enable the `should` syntax in your config:</strike>

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |c|
    c.syntax = [:should, :expect]
  end
end
```

The replacement syntax for `stub_chain` is:

```
allow(object).to receive_message_chain(:one, :two, :three).and_return(:four)
expect(object.one.two.three).to eq(:four)
```

More information about this and its usage in:

- The [pull request in rspec-mocks](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/pull/467)
- The [feature examples in rspec-mocks](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/master/features/message_expectations/message_chains_using_expect.feature)

As of this writing, the change to `receive_message_chain` will be included in the `3.0.0.beta2` release of rspec-mocks (see the [Changelog](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/master/Changelog.md)).  If you want it *right now*, you'll have to live on the bleeding edge and add the specific commit reference in your Gemfile to get `receive_message_chain` working:

```
gem 'rspec-mocks', github: 'rspec/rspec-mocks', ref: '4662eb0'
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't actually answer your question about getting rid of the deprecation message, which I was unable to do, even with the pre-release version of rspec-mocks and
`c.syntax = [:should, :expect]`  set explicitly in my RSpec config.

<strike>So, I would say your options are to either wait until `3.0.0.beta2` is released and see if the deprecation notices get fixed with your existing code at that time, or bring in the very latest changes and change your syntax to `receive_message_chain`.</strike>

See [Myron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20296359/567863) for the actual solution.

Comment: Have you tried this with `stub_chain`? Even with `:should` explicitly enabled, the warning remains with the version on github tagged `v3.0.0.beta1`, which I presume is the latest.

Comment: Good catch. It doesn't work with `v3.0.0.beta1`, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that worked for me - I'm using Rails 4.1.7 :

Inside spec/spec_helpber.rb, set rspec-expectations’ and/or rspec-mocks’ syntax as following:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.syntax = [:should, :expect]
  end
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.syntax = [:should, :expect]
  end
end
```

Hope this helps someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who wants to upgrade an old project to the new syntax, there is a tool [here](http://yujinakayama.me/transpec/).

As mentioned in the [Relish blog](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/syntax-configuration), they will probably move the should syntax into an external gem in the future, this leads me to believe that it will eventually be made obsolete.