# issue with stubs and rspec old syntax

Tags: ruby, rspec, stubs

I am writing some code and using rspec but received a warning that the syntax is old and i can't quite figure out how i should be writing it instead?

```
it "should calculate the value correctly" do 
        mock_cards = [Card.new(:clubs, 5), Card.new(:diamonds, 10)]
        hand = Hand.new
        hand.stub(:cards) { cards } #stub out cards and have it return cards
        expect(hand.value).to eq (15)
    end
```

The error message is as follows: Using `stub` from rspec-mocks' old `:should` syntax without explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use the new `:expect` syntax or explicitly enable `:should` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it like this instead:

```
allow(hand).to receive(:cards) { cards }
```

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#method-stubs