# Testing with rspec .consider_all_requests_local = false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, rspec-rails

I'm using in my **application_controller** : `.consider_all_requests_local` like

```ruby
  unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
    rescue_from ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest, :with => :render_404
  end
```

This return 404 if ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest is raised. In local environnement it's not raised, it's good for debugging. 
For this part it's working. But I would like to test it with rspec.

I've tried something like

```ruby
describe 'ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest render 404' do
    before { Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local = false }
    controller do
      def index
        raise ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest
      end
    end

    subject { xhr :get, :index, format: :js }

    its(:status) { is_expected.to eq 404 }
end
```

Two things. I probably not raise in the proper way. Locally the error occurs when *mywebsite.com/editor/fckeditor.js* is called. Didn't found a way to call a specific url.

Second problem, the *before* doesn't change the `Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local` state.

I get :

```ruby
1) ApplicationController ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest render 404 status
     Failure/Error: raise ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest
     ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest:
       ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue looks to be caused by your `unless` check being performed at class load time. This means the very first time the class is loaded the value in the application config is checked and the `rescue_from` is either set or not set.

At the most basic workaround, you would need to use `load` to cause that file to get re-read once the setting has been changed. However, as is, once the `rescue_from` is turned on, loading the file again won't cause it to turn off.

The next alternative is to use [`rescue_from(with:)`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rescue-from) which delegates to a helper or [the block form](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html#method-i-rescue_from). You can use this helper to check the value and either handle the condition or not. However, considering this looks to be something you only want to do in a non-production environment, you could combine the two. Use the `unless` to verify that you are not in production, then use the with to check the config each time.

Something like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  unless Rails.env.production?
    rescue_from ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest do
      unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
        render_404
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry to comment on such an old answer. But I think there is an issue here that you actually don't want to rescue if Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local is true. While this solution will skip the rendering of the 404 if it's true it will still swallow the exception?

Comment: Good point, @JackCasey . That is a valid concern. Since the exception is passed to any `rescue_from` error handler methods, you can and should re-raise the exception in the `else` case (if `Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local` is true). I posted an answer with the way I ended up doing it...

Comment: Rather than checking `consider_all_requests_local`, I would recommend checking `action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions`, like Rails does in [ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/DebugExceptions.html), as suggested in http://atodorov.org/blog/2016/04/27/changing-rails-consider_all_requests_local-in-rspec-fails/. That is a more direct flag to check for whether it is supposed to render the development/diagnostic "detailed" exceptions error page. I added a simple `show_detailed_exceptions?` method to make it easier to check (see my answer below).

Answer (score 1):

Try mocking it instead of setting:

```
before { Rails.stub_chain('application.config.consider_all_requests_local').and_return(false) }
```

More info [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-0/docs/stubs/stub-a-chain-of-methods)

This syntax is deprecated, so you can either turn off the deprecation warning or use the new 'workaround'

```
allow(object).to receive_message_chain(:one, :two, :three).and_return(:four)
expect(object.one.two.three).to eq(:four)
```

as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20296359/2882921)

Comment: Thanks for your anser Piotr, but this syntax is deprecated : `Failure/Error: before { Rails.stub_chain('application.config.consider_all_requests_local').and_return(false) }
       Using `stub_chain` from rspec-mocks' old `:should` syntax without explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use the new `:expect` syntax or explicitly enable `:should` instead.`

Answer (score 0):

I used to have a guard around my `rescue_from` config, too, like:

```
unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
  rescue_from Exception, with: :render_error
  …
end
```

... which worked fine, until I was trying to figure out how to make it handle errors and show pretty custom error pages (like it does in production) in some *tests*. @Aaron K's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31120314/47185) was helpful in explaining why the check can't be evaluated within the class definition, and has to be checked within the actual error handler (at run time) instead. But that only solved part of the problem for me.

Here's what I did...

In `ApplicationController`, remember to re-raise any errors if the `show_detailed_exceptions` flag (a more appropriate check than `consider_all_requests_local`) is true. In other words, only do the production error handling if the app/request is configured to handle errors for production; otherwise "pass" and re-raise the error.

```rb
  rescue_from Exception,                           with: :render_error
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound,        with: :render_not_found
  rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError,      with: :render_not_found
  rescue_from AbstractController::ActionNotFound,  with: :render_not_found

  def show_detailed_exceptions?
    # Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local causes this to be set to true as well.
    request.get_header("action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions")
  end

  def render_not_found(exception = nil, template = 'errors/not_found')
    raise exception if show_detailed_exceptions?
    logger.error exception if exception
    render template, formats: [:html], status: :not_found
  end

  def render_error(exception)
    raise exception if show_detailed_exceptions?
    deliver_exception_notification(exception)
    logger.error exception

    # Prevent AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in case we've already rendered something
    method(:response_body=).super_method.call(nil)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render 'errors/internal_server_error', formats: [:html], status: :internal_server_error }
      format.any  { raise exception }
    end
  end
```

Add to `spec/support/handle_exceptions_like_production.rb`:

```
shared_context 'handle_exceptions_like_production', handle_exceptions_like_production: true do
  before do |example|
    case example.metadata[:type]
    when :feature
      method = Rails.application.method(:env_config)
      allow(Rails.application).to receive(:env_config).with(no_args) do
        method.call.merge(
          'action_dispatch.show_exceptions' => true,
          'action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions' => false,
          'consider_all_requests_local' => true
        )
      end
    when :controller
      # In controller tests, we can only test *controller* behavior, not middleware behavior.  We
      # can disable show_detailed_exceptions here but we can *only* test any behaviors that depend
      # on it that are defined in our *controller* (ApplicationController). Because the request
      # doesn't go through the middleware (DebugExceptions, ShowExceptions) — which is what actually
      # renders the production error pages — in controller tests, we may not see the exact same
      # behavior as we would in production. Feature (end-to-end) tests may be needed to more
      # accurately simulate a full production stack with middlewares.
      request.set_header 'action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions', false
    else
      raise "expected example.metadata[:type] to be one of :feature or :controller but was #{example.metadata[:type]}"
    end
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include_context 'handle_exceptions_like_production', :handle_exceptions_like_production
end
```

Then, in end-to-end (feature) tests where you want it to handle exceptions like it does in production (in other words, to *not* treat it like a local request), just add `:handle_exceptions_like_production` to your example group:

```rb
describe 'something', :handle_exceptions_like_production do
  it …
end
```

For example:

`spec/features/exception_handling_spec.rb`:

```rb
describe 'exception handling', js: false do
  context 'default behavior' do
    it do |example|
      expect(example.metadata[:handle_exceptions_like_production]).to eq nil
    end

    describe 'ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound' do
      it do
        expect {
          visit '/users/0'
        }.to raise_exception(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
      end
    end

    describe 'ActionController::RoutingError' do
      it do
        expect {
          visit '/advertisers/that_track_you_and_show_you_personalized_ads/'
        }.to raise_exception(ActionController::RoutingError)
      end
    end

    describe 'RuntimeError => raised' do
      it do
        expect {
          visit '/test/exception'
        }.to raise_exception(RuntimeError, 'A test exception')
      end
    end
  end

  context 'when :handle_exceptions_like_production is true', :handle_exceptions_like_production do
    describe 'ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => production not_found page' do
      it do
        expect {
          visit '/users/0'
        }.to_not raise_exception
        expect_not_found
      end
    end

    describe 'ActionController::RoutingError => production not_found page' do
      it do
        visit '/advertisers/that_track_you_and_show_you_personalized_ads/'
        expect_not_found
      end
    end

    describe 'RuntimeError => production not_found page' do
      it do
        visit '/test/exception'
        expect_application_error
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It can also be used in controller tests — if you have production error-handling defined in your `ApplicationController`. `spec/controllers/exception_handling_spec.rb`:

```rb
describe 'exception handling' do
  context 'default behavior' do
    describe UsersController do
      it do
        expect {
          get 'show', params: {id: 0}
        }.to raise_exception(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
      end
    end

    describe TestController do
      it do
        expect {
          get 'exception'
        }.to raise_exception(RuntimeError, 'A test exception')
      end
    end
  end

  context 'when handle_exceptions_like_production: true', :handle_exceptions_like_production do
    describe UsersController do
      it do
        expect {
          get 'show', params: {id: 0}
        }.to_not raise_exception
        expect(response).to render_template('errors/not_found')
      end
    end

    describe TestController do
      it do
        expect {
          get 'exception'
        }.to_not raise_exception
        expect(response).to render_template('errors/internal_server_error')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Tested with: `rspec 3.9`, `rails 5.2`