# How to specify the RSpec "syntax" parameter on the command line?

Tags: ruby, command-line, rspec, syntax

We have a shell script which launches our RSpec tests. It looks something like this:

```
args+=(
  "--format" "html"
  "--out" "$to_dir/index.html"
)

"$rspec_dir/rspec" "${args[@]}" "$tests_to_run"
exit $?
```

When trying to upgrade RSpec, I'm getting an error that the `:should` syntax is deprecated, and we need to explicitly enable it like so: [How to avoid deprecation warning for stub_chain in RSpec 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275510/how-to-avoid-deprecation-warning-for-stub-chain-in-rspec-3-0)

However, since we're not using Rake, I need to figure out a way to do this when launching rspec through the command line.  But when I try adjusting the command line options like so:

```
./rspec --format "html" --out "index.html" --syntax ":should"
```

It says `--syntax` is not a valid option.  How can I enable this deprecated syntax while invoking rspec directly through the command line?

(We can't use Rake because our internal build tools don't support it. That's why I need to find out how to do this through the command line.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't configure RSpec expectations and mocks syntax on the command line. Edit your project's `spec/spec_helper.rb` to include the following:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.syntax = [:should, :expect]
  end
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.syntax = [:should, :expect]
  end
end
```

After you're upgraded, you'll probably want to change all of your examples to use the new syntax (probably with [transpec](https://github.com/yujinakayama/transpec)) and then disable the `:should` syntax.

More here https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/syntax-configuration and here https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/old-syntax/stub